# SWF -> Compatible YouTube format and retain ActionScript

Tags: flash, youtube, codec, swf

I have an swf (just a sequence of slides with audio, timing controlled by actionscript) that I want to convert to a compatible YouTube format (flv, mp4, etc.). I've tried using the Moyea SWF4Tube software but when it was converted all of the timing was gone.

I'm fine with uploading as a swf, but the problem was (when I tried) that the codecs weren't appropriate.

Any help regarding this is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube hosts videos.  You'll have to convert your swf into a flv, mp4, or other format which youtube accepts.  All of your actionscript will be removed, there is no way you can keep action script in a purely video format.  Maybe if you rendered your video a certain way the renderer might pay attention to the timing or something and render it like you want, but you can't upload a video with actionscript to youtube and expect it to stay in there.

Comment: I'm just going to play it on desktop and screen record it. Thanks.